# Pushing to Bitbucket with SSH works, but without a private key on my server

Tags: ssh

How is it that I am successfully pushing to Bitbucket, when there is no private key file on my Digital Ocean server?

When I created my Digital Ocean server, I provided it with a public key. This key got stored in the `authorized_keys` file, which allows me to SSH into the server from my local computer.

Then, I set up a Bitbucket account, and added the same public key to the account. Now, I'm able to push and pull from the Bitbucket server without a password.  However, I am completely confused as to why this works.  There is no private key file on my Digital Ocean server, so how is it that I'm able to connect successfully? Does it somehow use the private key file from my local machine since that's what I used to connect to the Digital Ocean server?

**EDIT**
I just read about SSH Agent Forwarding. Is that what's happening? In the `~/.ssh/config` file on my local machine I have the following:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120

ForwardAgent yes
Host 128.host-that-is-not-bitbuck.com
ProxyCommand ssh also.not.bitbucket.net nc %h %p
```

Shouldn't this mean that agent forwarding is only enabled for the specific host listed?

Comment: SSH agent forwarding?

Comment: Please see my edit. Is that what's causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your config.

The man page says:

> The configuration files contain sections separated by ``Host'' specifications

Since your line `ForwardAgent yes` comes **before** the line `Host 128.host-that-is-not-bitbuck.com`, it belongs to the previous `Host` specification - and since that host is `*`, the `ForwardAgent` option applies to *all* hosts unless otherwise stated.

If you want the agent forwarding to only apply to one host, you must place it in the section which starts with that hostname.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, what would happen if those first two lines were removed? Which host would `ForwardingAgent yes` belong to?

Comment: The man page does not specifically say so, but as far as I've been able to ascertain any lines before the first `Host: ` line would be considered as belonging to an implicit `Host: *` specification. So it would then be used for all hosts. (You could still change it for a specific host or hosts by setting the option `ForwardingAgent no` for that one host or hosts.)